# DIJKSTRA EM JAVA

Tags: java, grafo

Olá.
Estou implementando um grafo e como algoritmo de menor caminho, estou utilizando o DIJKSTRA. 
O grafo indica a relação de gêneros e seus respectivos subgêneros.
O grafo é direcional, não ponderado e possui vértices isolados.
Segue código abaixo:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TratamentoArquivo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\MATEUS\\Documents\\R\\dados\\generosFinal.csv"; //LOCAL ONDE ESTÁ O ARQUIVO
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer((int) new File(fileName).length());

        String linha = in.readLine();

        while (linha != null) {
            sb.append(linha + "\n");
            linha = in.readLine();
        }

        in.close();
        String text = sb.toString();
        ArrayList<String> generos = new ArrayList<String>();

        int n = 1228;

        String lines[] = text.split("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            lines[i] = lines[i].replace("{", "");
            lines[i] = lines[i].replace("}", "");

            String temp[] = lines[i].split(";");
            String current = temp[0];
            generos.add(temp[0]);
            lines[i] = lines[i].replace(temp[0], generos.indexOf(current) + "");

            if (temp[1].contains(",")) {
                String temp2[] = temp[1].split(",");
                for (int j = 0; j < temp2.length; j++) {

                    if (!generos.contains(temp2[j])) {
                        generos.add(temp2[j]);
                    }

                    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(temp2[j], generos.indexOf(temp2[j]) + "");
                }
            } else {
                if (!generos.contains(temp[1]) && !temp[1].equals("NULL")) {
                    generos.add(temp[1]);
                    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(temp[1], generos.indexOf(temp[1]) + "");
                } else if (!temp[1].equals("NULL")) {
                    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(temp[1], generos.indexOf(temp[1]) + "");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total: " + generos.size());
        int adj[][] = new int[generos.size()][generos.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String temp[] = lines[i].split(";");

            if (temp[1].contains(",")) {
                String temp2[] = temp[1].split(",");
                for (int j = 0; j < temp2.length; j++) {
                    adj[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp2[j])] = 1;

                }
            } else {
                if (!temp[1].equals("NULL")) {
                    adj[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        //Inicializando o Dijkstra
        //Tentativa 2 DIJKSTRA
        int v = adj.length;
        boolean visitados[] = new boolean[v];
        int distancias[] = new int[v];
        distancias[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < v; i++) {
            distancias[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < v - 1; i++) {
            //Encontrando vertice com menor distância
            int verticeMinimo = encontrarVerticeMinimo(distancias, visitados);
            //System.out.println(verticeMinimo);
            visitados[verticeMinimo] = true;
            //Explorando Vizinhos
            for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
                if ((distancias[j] > (distancias[verticeMinimo] + adj[verticeMinimo][j])) && adj[verticeMinimo][j] == 1) {
                    distancias[j] = adj[verticeMinimo][j] + distancias[verticeMinimo];
                }
            }

        }

        //Impressão
        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + distancias[i]);
        }

    }

    public static int encontrarVerticeMinimo(int distancias[], boolean visitados[]) {

        int verticeMinimo = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < distancias.length; i++) {
            if (!visitados[i] && (verticeMinimo == -1 || distancias[i] < distancias[verticeMinimo])) {
                verticeMinimo = i;
            }
        }
        return verticeMinimo;
    }
}
```

Apesar de ter seguido vários tutorias e estudado o algoritmo, o vetor de distâncias está sendo alimentado apenas com resultados infinitos (com excessão do primeiro vértice).
Fiz diversas modificações no código com o objetivo de solucionar esse problema, a única coisa que foi alterada no resultado é que, para os vértices não isolados (ou seja, que possuem um subgênero), o valor "infinito" foi negativado.
[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-9WxMNofnBUU8MhlMm5vkjr_RpO8uIpF/view?usp=sharing) do arquivo com as informações de gêneros e subgêneros.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando uma forma "diferente" do algoritmo dijkstra, com a seguinte função:

```
public static int[] dijkstra2(int adj[][], int origem) {

        int tamanho = adj.length;
        boolean visitados[] = new boolean[tamanho];
        int distancias[] = new int[tamanho];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            distancias[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        distancias[origem] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++) {
            int menorVertice = encontrarVerticeMinimo(distancias, visitados);
            visitados[menorVertice] = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
                if (adj[menorVertice][j] != 0 && !visitados[j] && distancias[menorVertice] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    int novaDistancia = distancias[menorVertice] + adj[menorVertice][j];
                    if (novaDistancia < distancias[j]) {
                        distancias[j] = novaDistancia;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return distancias;
    }
```

O método chamado `encontrarMenorVertice` é o seguinte:

```
public static int encontrarVerticeMinimo(int distancias[], boolean visitados[]) {

        int verticeMinimo = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < distancias.length; i++) {
            if (!visitados[i] && (verticeMinimo == -1 || distancias[i] < distancias[verticeMinimo])) {
                verticeMinimo = i;
            }
        }
        return verticeMinimo;
    }
```

A solução foi utilizar cada vértice como origem em cada execução do algoritmo.